# Automapper instance configuration has not been initialized in xUnit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, xunit

I am writing some unit tests with xUnit on a Web API Asp.Net Core and I am testing my services.

I've made a builder class that creates mapper instances in order to create the class that needs IMapper in a constructor.

```
public IMapper Mapper()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<CustomerRoleProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<LicenseProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<TaxExemptionProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<BankProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<AddressProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<CustomerDetailsProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<CustomerProfile>();
        });
        return config.CreateMapper();
    }
```

But every time I use the mapper instance it is throwing this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Mapper not initialized
```

And if I try to assert the configuration, all the tests are failing

```
        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

But If I try to use the static instance with the same configuration it is not failing, but some tests are failing because the Automapper is already initialized if I have more test classes.

```
public IMapper Mapper() 
{ 
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Reset();
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
          cfg.AddProfile(new CustomerRoleProfile());
          cfg.AddProfile(new LicenseProfile());
          cfg.AddProfile(new TaxExemptionProfile());
          cfg.AddProfile(new BankProfile());
          cfg.AddProfile(new AddressProfile());
          cfg.AddProfile(new CustomerDetailsProfile());
          cfg.AddProfile(new CustomerProfile());
     });
     return Automapper.Mapper.Configuration.CreateMapper();
}
```

With the static Automapper all tests from one class, for example, this test is successful

```
[Fact]
    public async Task UpdateOrInsertCustomer()
    {
        var customer = new CustomerCreateDto() { CustomerId = 1, StoreId = 1, CardTypeCode = "GO", InvoiceTypeCode = "PRO", SelfScanningAllowed = true, TradeId = 12345, CountryCode = "ROU" };
        var result = await _customerService.UpdateOrInsert(customer);
        result.Should().BeTrue();
    }
```

And some test from another class is failing, for example this one

```
[Theory]
    [InlineData(1, 1, null)]
    public async Task GeValidCustomerDetails(int customerId, int storeId, int? cardHolderId)
    {
        var result = await _detailsService.GetAsync(customerId, storeId, cardHolderId);
        if (!cardHolderId.HasValue)
            result.Should().NotBeNull().And.Subject.Should().BeOfType<OrganizationDto>();
        else
            result.Should().NotBeNull().And.Subject.Should().BeOfType<PersonDto>()
                .And.Subject.As<PersonDto>().CardHolderId.Should().Be(cardHolderId.Value);
        result.CustomerId.Should().Be(customerId);
        result.StoreId.Should().Be(storeId);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a workaround, I've used the static instance with a static wrapper and a lock to avoid race condition and it worked for all unit tests.
I do not know why the mapper configuration instance didn't work.

Comment: You should switch to the instance based API.

Comment: When I tried to use the mapper configuration instance, the assert configuration is valid fails. Only in the unit test. I'm only using this static instance in the xUnit project

Comment: You shouldn't be using anything static. Check [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Static-and-Instance-API.html).